# setting a uitableviewcontroller as rootviewcontroller for uinavigationcontroller in storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, uistoryboard

I am developing an iPhone application in which I have embedded `UITabbarController` and `UINavigationController` in my storyboard. when I select the first tab, it loads the navigation controller with a uitablecontroller as its rootviewcontroller. I have set the same `UITableViewController` again as the `rootviewcontroller` for the next navigation controller correspondingly to the next tab. but its not loading anything and I see a black screen. my question is whether i can set a single `UITableViewController` as a `rootviewcontroller` for different navigation controllers where each of this navigation controllers are embedded in different tabs in a storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. A view controller can be in the stack of at most one navigation controller.

Comment: @krishh: You are welcome! - If you think that this answers your question, don't forget to "accept" it.